# EM can not resolve configured mapping [EclipseLink-197]

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem with resolving entities during entity manager startup.

Now it falls with following error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-197] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
Description: The mapping [an_div] is not the appropriate type for this
descriptor Mapping:
org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[an_div-->div]
Descriptor:
EISDescriptor(com.cloudyle.paasplus.api.fhir.model.dstu2.composite.NarrativeDt
--> [DatabaseTable(DATATYPE), DatabaseTable(NARRATIVEDT)])
```

The abstract class configuration:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@UuidGenerator(name = "UUID_GEN_SQL")
@NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public abstract class AbstractBaseResource
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1212459053211153257L;
  protected static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractBaseResource.class);
  public static final String DELIMITER = ", ";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID_GEN_SQL")
  @Column(name = "_id")
  private String id;

  @Version
  @Field(name = "object_version")
  private Long objectVersion;

  @Embedded
  @Field(name = "text")
  private NarrativeDt text;

// getter and setter
// ...
}
```

A simple entity class:

```
@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public class Account extends AbstractBaseResource
    {   
    @Field(name = "name")
    private String an_name;

// other fields + getter and setter
// ...
}
```

The embbedable entity where the problem could be:

```
@Embeddable
@NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@Customizer(DtChildCustomizer.class)
public class NarrativeDt extends Datatype
{

  @Field(name = "status")
  private String an_status;

  @Field(name = "div")
  private String an_div;

// getter and setter
// ...
}
```

The extended embbedable:

```
@Embeddable
@NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED)
@Customizer(DtParentCustomizer.class)
public abstract class Datatype implements IDatatype, Serializable
{
  @Field(name = "element_specific_id")
  private String an_elementSpecificId;

// getter and setter
// ...

}
```

The child customizer:

```
public class DtChildCustomizer implements Serializable, DescriptorCustomizer
{
  @Override
  public void customize(final ClassDescriptor descriptor)
  {
    descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().setParentClass(Datatype.class);
  }
}
```

And the parent customizer:

```
public class DtParentCustomizer implements Serializable, DescriptorCustomizer
{
  @Override
  public void customize(final ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception
  {
    descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().setSingleTableStrategy();
    final DatabaseField indicatorField = new DatabaseField();
    indicatorField.setName("classType");
    indicatorField.setLength(255);
    indicatorField.setType(java.lang.String.class);
    descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().setClassIndicatorField(indicatorField);
    descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().useClassNameAsIndicator();
  }
}
```

I can not understand why eclispeLink have a problem to resolve simple mapping an_div->div.

All suggestion will be appreciated, I already spent too much time working on it. I can not see the mapping problem :(

Kind regards